# Duplicate column name in SQL

Tags: sql, alias

I've wanted to create a view in my sql but I've been getting this error:

> Duplicate column name 'product_id'

Here's my query:

```
CREATE VIEW product_view AS

SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
    JOIN storeitems on products.product_id = storeitems.product_id;
```

I believe creating an alias would solve the problem but then I don't know how to do it. I hope you could help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the error because both tables in your query has a column named product_name and selected column names must be unique.

You make your aliases like this:

```
CREATE VIEW product_view AS SELECT p.product_name, si.product_name StoreItemsProductName -- continue with what you want to select...
FROM products p JOIN storeitems si
on p.product_id=si.product_id;
```

Comment: Do I really have to select each field in the table? Can't I just use the wildcard *?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you "spell out" each field in the SELECT of the view, so that it doesn't change if the involved tables change. In this case, you have no other option. Alternatively, you can SELECT p.* and then "spell out" the columns of the second table, but you need to spell out columns to give them an alias.

Answer (score 3):

yes, creating an column alias would solve the problem and you do it like

```
select column1 as test_column
```

But if this your original query then I doubt you won't get this error since you are selecting from single table called `products` and obviously same table won't have multiple column with same name.

Anyway you can modify your query to be like

```
CREATE VIEW product_view AS
SELECT p.product_id as product_product_id, 
si.product_id as storeItem_product_id
FROM
    products p
    JOIN storeitems si on p.product_id = si.product_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably both the `products` table and the `storeitems` table have a column named `product_name`.

```
CREATE VIEW product_view AS SELECT * FROM products p JOIN storeitems si on p.product_id=si.product_id;
```

here `p` will be the alias for the `products` table and `si` will be the alias for `storeitems` table

Comment: If you provide aliases to the tables, probably you won't need to provide aliases for each column, and you can leave the wildcard `SELECT *`

Comment: I tried executing this query @sirnino but I still get the same error. In this case, do I really have to provide aliases for each column?

Comment: Wich DB are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports the `using` clause *and* you only have one duplicate column name, then you could do:

```
select *
from products p join
     storeitems si
     using (product_id);
```

In general, though, I think it is better to list out the columns in a view.  If one of the underlying tables changes the order or names of the columns, then this is safer.